Invoke-WebRequest pivot results
I need simple script which will execute Invoke-WebRequest command for each site saved in file.txt to display og:description from sites from file.
So far I dont have loop, but I am able to fetch og:description using script below
$response = Invoke-WebRequest https://www.w3schools.com/

[regex]$pattern = '"og:([^:]+?)" content="(.+?)"'

$pattern.Matches($response.Content).captures | ForEach-Object {
    ,$_.groups.value | ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Name  = $_[1]
            Value = $_[2]
        }
    }
} | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "description" -or $_.Name -eq "url" } | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\site_desc.csv" -NoTypeInformation


Problem is that results are not saved as I would excepted, so far I have
"Name","Value"
"description","FGH-5556"
"url","https://www.w3schools.com/"

and I need something like that, results in one line for each
"desciption","url"
"FGH-5556","https://www.w3schools.com/"
"....","...."
....

How I can convert result to looks more like csv instead of array
Thanks for support
